# How to detect mouse on Title of a Form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, hover, mouse, detect

Please take a look at this window form of mine:

[image]

How do I detect that my mouse is on the top of the title?
My purpose is, when the mouse leaving the TopMenu, it will hide the TopMenu.
When the mouse hoverOn the Title Form, i want to show the TopMenu again.

Just like when we show/hide Startmenu bar on windows similar like that.
What should I do to detect that my mouse is currently on the top of the title bar of that Form?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442725/how-to-get-mouse-events-from-outside-of-program-window

Comment: [**Please don't put tags in the title**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Comment: You will need to listen for the WM_NCMOUSEHOVER  message.  You can request that this message be generated using the [TrackMouseEvent function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646265(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: in code please @TnTinMn,... with vb flavour...

Comment: This site is not a code writing service!  Research the information that I and others provided and make an attempt at it.  Then ask about a specific issue.     [http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx](http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx) is also a good resource.

Comment: solved! @TnTinMn